# Cookies in UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch, cookies, uiwebview, ios

I have a UIWebView, and I don't want it to store an cookies, so just before the webview is loaded I do:

```
NSArray* cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Checking the count of cookies is 0 so they are all deleted. But when I go to stackoverflow it still recognizes my Google Account and logs me in. How does this happen? I though it worked with cookies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to deal with the exact same issue and I found 2 ways to deal with that problem.
I first noticed that cookies get (sometimes) set at weird times (Strange behaviour especially with ios 4.0).

- Instant deletion of cookies after the user was on a webview often didn't get me the expected results.

I then integrated a persistant, manual flag that was set True on a "logout" (aka clear all cookies / delete other user data) action.
upon the next login (aka user-login-based action) I cleared the cookies again (the same way you did it in your code-post).

Later I found out, that listening to `NSHTTPCookieManagerCookiesChangedNotification` and then deleting cookies worked really well too.

hope I could help.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the cookie acceptance policy instead:

```
[NSHTTPCookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever];
```

Comment: The problem is this stops cookies from being made I want to remove existing ones. Ideally clear all caches, cookies, local storage and other user data.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, based on your question I did not know what additional actions you wanted to perform.  Looks like you are looking for a full cache clear - not sure that is possible off hand.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Why do you need to wipe all caches, cookies, and local storage / user data?

Answer (score 0):

Use following and it will work..

```
   NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
   NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
   for(cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
      NSLog(@"cookie to be deleted:%@", cookie);
      [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

here don't miss last line [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; otherwise you will remain puzzle.