# Is it possible to change iOS Safari settings programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, safari, mobile-safari

Is it possible to change Safari settings in a native app like following :

1. Accept Cookies : Never
2. Javascript: Off
3. Clear History, clear cookies and clear cache

Is the above possible and legal to do in a native app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nop. You can change the cookie settings for **your app** only.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about a webview in your own application?

1) NO 
You can delete them though: [How to delete all cookies of UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471629/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-uiwebview) 
Also right after creation: [Cookies in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646879/cookies-in-uiwebview)

2) NO, its a system setting: [UIWebView: Can You Disable Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302975/uiwebview-can-you-disable-javascript)

3) There is no saved history in a webview. For cookies see 1),
for the Cache see: [How to clear UIWebView cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523435/how-to-clear-uiwebview-cache) 
Also interesting: [UIWebView cache in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057595/uiwebview-cache-in-ios) and [Clearing UIWebview cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache),

Comment: Thanks for the info, it was helpful. But I was asking about Safari.