# How to change safari setting programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, safari

is it posible to change Mac safari setting by app after getting user permission if yes then how its done by objective c code. if no why.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632294/is-it-possible-to-change-ios-safari-settings-programmatically

Comment: where safari preference file located which have setting information like search engine

Comment: Which setting do you want to change?

Comment: search engine change programmatically by app or extension after getting user permission

Answer (score 0):

An application can only change settings of another application if sandbox is disabled, by editing the application settings dictionary file:

```
NSString *safariSettingsPath = [@"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSMutableDictionary *safariSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:safariSettingsPath];
safariSettings[@"ExtensionsEnabled"] = @(NO);
[safariSettings writeToFile:safariSettingsPath atomically:YES];
```