# UIWebView and Cookies

Tags: ios, uitableview, cookies, uiwebview

I have a `UITableView` with each row containing login information to a website.
Then once a row is tapped the `UIWebView` is being pushed into the main view.

Now when I login to a website with the same domain the `UIWebView` does not recognise the different subdomains and the website stays logged in because of Cookies.

What is the best way to give each row it's own `UIWebView` so that the correct cookies are given with the correct login?

I do not know the amount of accounts the user will have in the `UITableView`.

I was thinking of making pointers ending with an integer that matches the row, so I am just seeing if that is the right way to go about this problem.

Cheers

Comment: How about deleting the cookies for that website each time you push to uiwebview? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646879/cookies-in-uiwebview?rq=1

Comment: Yeah i'll look into that - was seeing if I could keep them - hence the the separate WebViews, but it may not be the best option memory wise.